Is there any way to check if grouping is active in AG-grid vue?
I am using row grouping panel for ag-grid in Vue. Here we can drop column headers to group by any field. Is there any ag-grid parameter or function to check if grouping is active at the moment or not?

were you able to get the server side pagination under control using vue3? If yes, can you help me with any complete example? Would really appreciate your efforts.

Yes, it's possible!
I'm going to show you two ag-grid callback functions, one of which is optional, but you can use it to perform other actions.
Here are the links to the documentation used:
https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-miscellaneous-stateUpdated
https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/row-dragging/#row-drag-events
They are: dragStopped and stateUpdated.
What are they for?
dragStopped is triggered after you drop the row in the grouping panel, so you can perform some action this way.
stateUpdated is triggered after dropping the row in the grouping panel, sorting the column.
Therefore, you will fire this event several times and you will need to filter the event you want by the array of sources that will be inside your callback, for example, when you drag and drop the row into the panel, it will fire with the source ["columnVisibility"] and after it's done: [“columnSizing”, “rangeSelection”], so if you remove the row from the panel using the “x” icon, the sources [“columnVisibility”, “rangeSelection”] will be fired.
It's a bit long, but I think you get the idea... to check all the sources, follow the documentation.
Here's a brief code snippet showing how it happens in practice:
 <ag-grid-vue
      style="width: 500px; height: 500px"
      class="ag-theme-quartz"
      :columnDefs="columnDefs"
      :rowData="rowData"
      @drag-stopped="onDragStopped"
      @state-updated="onStateUpdated"
      >
    </ag-grid-vue>

Remember to add the events that are fired from the ag-grid: @drag-stopped and @state-updated.
And onDragStopped and onStateUpdated are the functions you can define and use:
const onDragStopped = (e:any) => {
  console.log('onDragStopped', e);
};

const onStateUpdated = (e:any) => {
  console.log('onStateUpdated', e);
};

In the code snippet above, I'm using Vue 3 with Composition Api and Typescript, but you can easily turn this into a method if it's Vue 2.
Here's an example of what to look for in the console.log:
{
    "type": "stateUpdated",
    "sources": [ "rangeSelection" , "rowGroup" ],
    "rowGroup": {
        "groupColIds": [
            "your.column"
        ]
    },
}

I hope this helps you (even if a little late) and others who have this question.
